# nodejs memory leak ( async.queue and request)

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I have a very simple crawler, it goes through 250 pages, allocates roughly 400mb memory and never frees it. I have no idea how to fix it, perhaps someone notices something off and kindly lets me know.

```
function scrape(shop, o, cb, step) {

    var itemz = []

    var q = async.queue(function (o, cb) {
        req({
            url: o.url
        }, function (e, r) {
            if (e) throw (e)
            cb()
            o.cb(r.body)
        })
    }, o.threads)
    var get = function (url, cb) {
        q.push({
            url: url,
            cb: cb
        })
    }

    var url = 'https://www.host.com'
    var total, done = 0,
        itemsPerPage = 24

    get(url, function (r) {

        pages = (r.match(/data-page="(\d+)"/g));
        pages = pages[pages.length - 2].split("data-page=\"")[1].split('"')[0] || 1;
        pages = Math.min(pages, 10) // limit to 10 pages max (240 items)

        for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
            get(url + '&page=' + i, scrapeList)
        }
        total = pages + pages * itemsPerPage
    })

    // - extract the transaction links from the pages: 
    //   and add them to queue
    function scrapeList(r) {
        var itemsFound = 0

        r.replace(/href="(https:\/\/www.host.com\/listing\/(\d+).*)"/g, function (s, itemUrl, dateSold) {
            itemsFound++
            get(itemUrl, function (r) {
                scrapeItem(r, itemUrl, dateSold)
                step(++done, total)
                if (done == total) onend()
            })
        })

        total -= itemsPerPage - itemsFound // decrease expected items, if less items per page found than initially expected
        step(++done, total)
    }

    // - from item page extract the details, and add to items array
    function scrapeItem(r, itemUrl, dateSold) {

        var d = {}
        d.url = itemUrl;

        d.date = new Date(Date.now())

        d.quantity = 1;

        itemz.push(d)
    }

    // - when no more requests in a queue (on drain), group items by title
    function onend() {

        cb(null, itemz);

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the `scrape(...)` function?  It returns an array to its callback.  If you are storing that array persistently, that would be a set of persistent data.

Comment: I'm storing it in array and setInterval goes through that array every minute and cleans it ( delete cache[k] );

Comment: Have you run heap snapshots and examined what is building up in the heap?

Comment: Yes, i did. It's all under string constructor. Looks like it keeps storing request page content for some reason.

Comment: What does `o.cb(r.body)` do inside of the callback to `req()`?  We're flying a little blind here because you don't show how all this is called and what is and isn't stored or might be captured in a closure.  Also, lots of single letter arguments/variables like `o`, `e`, `r`, `d` do not enhance the readability of your code for someone who has not seen it before.  More descriptive names would help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where i scraped a host and used cheerio to parse the html, but cheerio using lodash internally had memory leaks that it never released ,so i found a work around of triggering `GC` (garbage collector) on regular intervals to free up memory,just call `global.gc();` after reqular intervals, while running your script with flag `--expose-gc`

eg: `node <script>.js --expose-gc.`

This is not a ideal solution but its a quick fix for standalone script like yours
 see [here](https://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/),Also do not keep the interval too short as i noticed garbage collection is CPU intensive and also delays the event loop so every 5 to 10 seconds should do the trick.

Also i found a interesting read about v8 garbage collection [here](http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection)

Comment: Interesting, I always thought that if memory can be freed by garbage collection (forced or not), it's not leaking.

Comment: @robertklep after profiling my application i found out that cheerio had huge arrays and object created due to its use of loadash.

Comment: @robertklep if you are interested see the 2nd link in my answer, its gives some clarification on how v8 garbage collection works.